# Search for menu bar commands on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

Ubuntu's Unity interface has a feature called "HUD" that allows the user to search for commands in the menu bars of all applications. Is similar software available for Windows that can do the same thing (i. e., allow the user to enter a search query, and then display relevant menu bar commands?)

Comment: i think it's in mac too

Comment: @naxa I've noticed it in Mac too (for some applications, such as Abobe Illustrator). Is it available for all Mac applications, or only some of them?

Comment: it's a system feature, see: http://mactoids.com/help-menu-search-in-mac-os-x-leopard/ but I don't use a Mac too often so haven't tested it very thoroughly for application support. There is a popular related question, same intent: http://superuser.com/questions/289600/

Comment: I think it's for the Mac in general, simply. The Finder is almost the only thing I think Windows could use that Mac OS has.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any software that does this system-wide, but there is this [Office Labs extension](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28559) that adds that functionality to Office 2007/2010.